# How to store/retrieve data in OS X applications?

Tags: database, xcode, macos, storage

I am starting to develop my first Mac OS X application using Xcode. My background is LAMP, so I typically store everything in a MySQL database. What's the correspondent in OS X?

My application will simply allow the user to enter new data, and then to retrieve it based on filters.

I am not looking for specific code, but for some pointers as to how storing data into databases work in OS X. I have found very little resource on this subject.

Comment: You can still use SQL if you want, but the most common techniques are [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html), or NSCoding for lightweight persistence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite is used in many situations where a database server isn't required. Apple uses it for things like their Mail app. You can use some of the built-ins of Xcode (like sqlite.h) or a command-line shim of some kind. Other variants of SQL will require a separate download.

Core Data uses an object model which may be more convenient in a storage sense, though it has a moderate footprint and learning curve, and it's not cross-platform. Which may be important for the data migration that's common with database work.

If you're just starting with desktop programming from a LAMP background, you could look into "wrapper" apps that let you package LAMP software on the desktop with a native GUI. Might be easier than going Objective-C from scratch since it's one of the more obtuse languages out there. Xojo is also nice if you're used to VisualBasic and need to do cross-platform work.

Comment: Thanks @Beejor. This was very helpful. I want to avoid wrapping anything. I actually want to learn Swift and Object C. I will take a look at Core Data, and if too difficult I can fallback to SQL lite.

Comment: @gdaniel No problem. Core Data is used pretty heavily in iOS, which may be useful for skill and code migration to that platform if that's your thing. Also the other day I looked inside the backup file format that you can export from the Address Book/Contacts app. It's SQLite, though with a unique structure you may find interesting (.abcddb). Of course you can use any DB structure you want, but I wonder if Apple has a standard way they do their database files, and the specific reasons why.